# Deduce relations between sides of a triangle if $\cos A + \cos C= 2 - 2\cos B$

Tags: sequences-and-series, geometry, trigonometry, triangles

If the relation between the cosines of the angles of a triangle is given by

$\cos A + \cos C= 2 - 2\cos B$

then what relation do the sides of the triangle follow? That is, are they in Arithmetic, Geometric or Harmonic progression?

I tried using trigonometric addition formulae and then deducing the results. I applied $\ cosx + \ cosy $ formula along with $A + B + C = \pi$ but I could not solve the question.

Please Note: This question is intended to be a multiple choice question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us assume, additionally, that we have a right triangle with hypotenuse $c=1$. Then the given conditions result in the equations
$$
b = 2 - 2a, \qquad a^2+b^2=1.
$$
Solving these equations we find 
$$
a=3/5, \qquad b=4/5, \qquad c=1.
$$
Thus a right triangle with sides $a,b,c$ *in an arithmetic progression* satisfies the given conditions.

**Note:** We have treated this as a multiple choice question. By producing one example of *arithmetic progression* we excluded the other options.

Comment: `Let us assume, additionally` The posted question didn't ask for, or allow for, any additional assumptions. I don't see how you can just "*assume*" it's a right triangle out of the blues.

Comment: I treated this as a multiple choice question. By producing one example of AP we excluded the other options.

Comment: Then you should make that plenty clear in the body of the answer.

Comment: @dxiv I intended this question to be asked as a multiple choice question. So the assumption is not wrong. I apologise for not including the type of question.

Comment: @AnanthKamath Then *you* should make that more clear in the question. It's not obvious (wasn't to me, at least) that the question was meant as a multiple choice. Even less so since the [other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2084979/if-in-a-triangle-cosa-cosb-2-cosc-2-prove-that-the-sides-of-th) shows that this is answerable without much guessing.

Comment: @dxiv I have added a note. Thanks for pointing out the mistake.